# Command works in cmd.exe, but not in *.bat file

Tags: cmd, path

I want to find path to executable from path system variable on windows and assign it to variable. (unix 'which' command)

When I open cmd.exe and type:

```
for %i in (cmd.exe) do @set cmdPath=%~$PATH:i
```

It works (I test it with 'echo %cmdPath%')

But when I copy this line to .bat file it throws me an error during execution that "~$PATH:i was not expected in this moment"

I don't know why, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the FOR documention (type `help for` or `for /?`).

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
>   from %I.

You just need to double your percents when in a batch file.

```
for %%i in (cmd.exe) do set cmdPath=%%~$PATH:i
```

Note that `%COMSPEC%` should already hold the full path to cmd.exe

Comment: Thank you for full answer. cmd.exe was just an example (notepad.exe would be better). I was looking for cmake.exe path.