# Mogrify -resize works in cmd.exe but not in .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, image-processing, cmd, imagemagick

If i do it manually with cmd.exe mogrify works a charm.

However, when I run it from a .bat file it fails. I tried some with convert too just in case but no joy. The error code is always `The command "mogrify" is missing or not found`.

I thought I had found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897536/command-works-in-cmd-exe-but-not-in-bat-file) but as my images are being created and the active directory is where I want it I don't see how that could be the issue.

I have opened a console, cd to the new directory created by the above, copied and pasted one of the below mogrify commands and it works fine.

So I reckon it's either down to a difference between cmd and bat that I'm not aware of or something in imagemagick. Either way I'm new to both so hoping someone can help me.

Environment variable is also correct

Code is as follows:

```
set path=icons %date:~0% %time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%\
md "%path%"
cd %path%

copy %1 "ios_144x144.png"
copy %1 "android_ldpi.png"
copy %1 "android_mdpi.png"
copy %1 "android_hdpi.png"
copy %1 "android_xhdpi.png"
copy %1 "ios_57x57.png"
copy %1 "ios_72x72.png"
copy %1 "ios_114x114.png"
copy %1 "ios_144x144.png"

pause //Check here to see if dir and images created and that command line is now in %path%. In test runs all is okay as far as here

convert -resize 36x36 android_ldpi.png
mogrify -resize 48x48 android_mdpi.png
mogrify -resize 72x72 android_hdpi.png
mogrify -resize 96x96 android_xhdpi.png
mogrify -resize 114x114 ios_114x114.png
mogrify -resize 144x144 ios_144x144.png
mogrify -resize 72x72 ios_72x72.png
mogrify -resize 57x57 ios_57x57.png


echo Verzeichnis %path% fertig.

pause>nul
```

Comment: I think your path is wrong. Is convert.exe in the directory "icons"? Try typing "echo %PATH%" at your normal prompt and you will see the PATH you need for convert.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If programs are not in current directory, they are searched in the directories indicated by the PATH environment variable.

But in your code, you are changing this variable, so, no executables are found if they are not in the same directory you are working.

Change the name of the variable to not collide with any of the system standard environment variables.